# Can a WCF service be modular like a WEB API service?

Tags: .net, wcf, asp.net-web-api

All the WCF services that I've already seen were a single 'god' interface/class with a bunch of methods. If I wanted to have another module I always created a new service.

With WEB API I don't have to do it because I can develop several controllers responsible for different functionality.

Is it true that a WCF service is always such a 'god' class with many methods or do I miss something?

I've read many comparisons between WCF vs WEB API but I did't see this point mentioned by any of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic a set of controllers in WebAPI by utilizing c# `partial` modifier. But this will probably double a number of files in a project due to the need to have an interface and its implementation in WCF (if you keep them separated).

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that when you say "WCF Service", you're referring to a SOAP service. Because WCF also supports REST-style services.

You can develop a WCF service however you like.

One difference is that WEB API services do not expose metadata about themselves. If you add (or remove) a controller, then it doesn't affect the metadata sent to requesting clients, because there *is* none.

If you add or remove a service contract, or add or remove operations form an existing service contract, then you change the metadata available to clients. Some of those clients might either break (clients like PHP that use the metadata at runtime), or might simply not be able to work with the new service contracts (because they have no proxy classes to match it).

Answer (score 1):

By architecture, a WCF service is more "modular" than a WEB API service. You've already seen were a single 'god' interface/class with a bunch of methods, likely because the prior developers might have typically the following malpractices.

1. One interface for all methods
2. Mix interfaces and implementations in the same assembly

If the software architecture is designed properly, most or all the business logic should be encapsulated in model classes which have no couplings with WCF or Web API, so you codes of Web Api or WCF should be thin.

Comment: @John, this was by design, though in practice, there have been more and more B2B Web services are implemented through Web API / RESTful. More exactly it is your business models and operation models determines which technologies to use. My intention of mentioning B2B and B2C is to raise the awareness of business models and operation models, though this could be out of context in such Q&A forum.

Comment: you are right John. Just removed mentioning b2b b2c.